# VBA Macro across multiple worksheets

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I am trying to run a single macro which performs functions on multiple worksheets. Let's say I have assigned the macro button on worksheet 4. I have listed the functions I want it to perform step by step:

1) Select certain cells in worksheet 4 and copy to adjacent cells in worksheet 4.
2) delete range of cells in worksheet 3.
3) CUT range of cells in worksheet 2 then paste this range of cells into worksheet 3.
4) Take range of cells from a separate workbook and copy into worksheet 2. (I know this is an entirely different problem as the workbook is automatically published and I will have to find a way to link the two.)
5) Update pivot tables located within Worksheet 4 and Worksheet 3.

I would love help on the first 3 functions of this. I've pasted my current code below.

```
Sub START()

Dim sh1 As Worksheet
Dim sh2 As Worksheet
Dim sh3 As Worksheet
Dim sh4 As Worksheet

Set sh1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Brand")
Set sh2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("CurrentWeek")
Set sh3 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("PriorWeek")
Set sh4 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Pivot")

sh4.Range("B29:B30").Select
Selection.Copy

sh4.Range("C29").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

sh3.Range("A4:AC1000").Select
Selection.Delete

sh2.Range("A4:AC1000").Select
Selection.Copy

sh3.Range("A4").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

End Sub
```

It works... but it only works when I'm in the right worksheet to perform a specific function.

Comment: Instead of unreadable variable names such as `sh1`, `sh2` etc. why not call them something useful and transparent like `shtBrand`, `shtCurrentWeek` etc. One guy at work does this exact same `sh1` `sh2` business and it drives everyone nuts when we try to read his code.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett Yes, that's actually a good idea. The reasoning I didn't do this at first is because in my business, no one knows how to code. This task i'm trying to automate has already been manually done for about 2-3 years. It's absurd, but that is a great idea! Thank you.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

By removing the `select`, the `selection` and the `activesheet`, you will be able to make this sheet-independent

```
Sub START()

Dim sh1 As Worksheet
Dim sh2 As Worksheet
Dim sh3 As Worksheet
Dim sh4 As Worksheet

Set sh1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Brand")
Set sh2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("CurrentWeek")
Set sh3 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("PriorWeek")
Set sh4 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Pivot")

sh4.Range("B29:B30").Copy sh4.Range("C29")

sh3.Range("A4:AC1000").Delete

sh2.Range("A4:AC1000").Copy sh3.Range("A4")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 6):

You are off to a great start. Just little more refinement and you'll have it.

Basically, there's no need to `.Select` your ranges (sheets, workbooks, etc), at least in this case. You can work directly with them and by using the `Copy` supply the destination where they will be copied.

See code below:

```
Sub START()

Dim sh1 As Worksheet
Dim sh2 As Worksheet
Dim sh3 As Worksheet
Dim sh4 As Worksheet
Dim wkb As Workbook

Set wkb = Workbooks("wkbName") '-> best to call workbooks by name, as opposed to "ActiveWorkbook", also best to set it to object

With wkb '-> now we can work with this object directly and succinctly

    Set sh1 = .Sheets("Brand")
    Set sh2 = .Sheets("CurrentWeek")
    Set sh3 = .Sheets("PriorWeek")
    Set sh4 = .Sheets("Pivot")

    sh4.Range("B29:B30").Copy sh4.Range("C29")

    'sh3.Range("A4:AC1000").Delete -> you don't need this if you are overwritting it

    sh2.Range("A4:AC1000").Copy sh3.Range("A4")

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Why is it necessary to kill the variables?

Comment: @Mattboy -> it's best practice to take them out of memory. For this small bit of code, not a big deal, but it can help when you have big code projects.

Comment: They get killed when you exit the sub anyway, but as Scott said, it's not a bad habit to have for when you actually need it.

Comment: Yes @nutsch, that was my thinking. To show people good habits, instead of ignoring it :)

Comment: Also @nutsch, I believe there are times that variables only appear to killed at `Exit Sub`, but don't actually release unless you tell it to release.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman: Setting all objects to `Nothing` at the end of every procedure will fill your code with mostly useless boilerplate junk. You only need to do this for objects whose `Class_Terminate` event handler interact in bad ways with global variables and objects -- which are themselves bad things that you should never use (with one noteworth exception being VBA's weird, native `Err` object which there is no way around). For `Workbook` and `Worksheet` objects this is irrelevant and therefore don't waste your breath on Nothing'ing everything.

Comment: Thank you @Jean-FrançoisCorbett. Appreciate the insight.

Answer (score 0):

sheets("name1").range("B29:B30").copy Destination:=sheets("name2").range("C29")

Will copy from one to another sheet assuming the sheet names are name1 and name2

Answer (score -2):

```
Sub START()

Sheet("Pivot").Range("B29:B30").Copy Sheet("Pivot").Range("C29")
Sheet("CurrentWeek").Range("A4:AC1000").Copy Sheet("PriorWeek").Range("A4")

End Sub
```

Comment: -1 What's the point in posting what is essentially a fragment of the already accepted answer?