# How do I apply an excel macro with a selection change event to all sheets?

Tags: excel, vba, selectionchanged

The macro is not working if I make it run on an active sheet in the code even if it is only attached to one sheet, but it works only for that sheet if I type only its name for the variable I'm using. How do I make it run on all sheets with selection change working?

Comment: Can you share what exactly is not working?

Comment: Look here to make the code independent of worksheets http://stackoverflow.com/a/13055043/266562

Comment: The event procedures like `Selection_Change` etc. apply only to the sheet where the code resides. It is possible of course to break up your code and call it from other worksheets' event handlers, but in order to suggest a decent solution, you're going to have to show us some of your code and describe in more detail what your problem is: Do you want a change on *any* sheet to trigger the *same* procedure just for that one sheet? Or do you want it to trigger some procedure to run on *all* (or some specific plural) sheets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just applied the Workbook_SheetSelectionChange event. Yes precisely that David. Thanks guys!